# Height auto is not working in a background div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JyZ67/)

I want to show a div which background is transparent, and the transparency is not affect on the top of the particular div. so i use the following html and css.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="transparncy"></div>
    <div id="contentdata">
        <div id="left">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <p></p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#content {
width:100%;
position:relative;  
color:#37475e;
}

#content #transparncy {
opacity:.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);  
-moz-opacity:0.4;   
background-color:Red;  
width:100%; 
min-height:250px; 
height:auto;
overflow:auto;
position:absolute;  
top:0px;  
left:0px;  
z-index:-1;
}

#contentdata {
position:relative;  
width:100%;
}

#left {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
#right {
float:right;
width:35%;
}
```

My problem is that when i add more data in #contentdata , i can adjust the height of #transparncy proportional to that (cant increase the background transparent div). How can i solve this problem. Please help me

Comment: Why are you using that height as diff div put content data under transparency checkout my demo at http://jsbin.com/iGEratu/1/edit

Comment: close </div> (transparncy) outside.. <div id="transparncy"> content data .......</div>

Comment: updated fiddle here.. http://jsfiddle.net/JyZ67/7/

Comment: @Indian: then the opacity of the content will be less

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JyZ67/8/ updated...

Comment: Sowmya answer also correct and its working too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving new blank div to transparency, add the same class name to `id="contentdata"` div and make `background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.4);`  this will not apply transparency to text but only for bg

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentdata" class="transparncy">...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contentdata .transparncy {  
    background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.4); 
    width:100%; 
    min-height:250px; 
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute;  
    top:0px;  
    left:0px;  
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius:5px;
 }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ezAjekA/2/)**

Comment: but this is not show the transparent background . please check my edited fiddle with this code http://jsfiddle.net/JyZ67/4/

Comment: You are adding `class="transparncy"` in main div that is why not visible. Add it in `id="contentdata"` div. And you have changed id name that is why. Check my edited answer.

Comment: but still there is problem the opacity of content is less, how can i solve this

Comment: what do u mean by opacity of content?? do u need transparency for content as well??

Comment: no i dont want the transparency in content. I need only the transparent background

Comment: @Parvathiiiii If you can check the fiddle in my answer properly, you wont see any transparency for content. Content is in black color.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer updated Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/JyZ67/8/)

The main problem is you use the `<div id="transparncy"></div>` not properly

```
 <div id="transparncy">
          contentdatas....
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by adding `bottom:0` to the `#transparncy` part of the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is quite simple and relevant to ask**

You have used min-height : 250px;
no matter what the height of inner/child conteht or div is parent div with min-height in your case  #content #transparncy will take minimum height of 250px

just remove min-height and i will work as height auto :)

updated  code :

```
#content #transparncy {
opacity:.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);  
-moz-opacity:0.4;   
background-color:Red;  
width:100%; 
height:auto;
overflow:auto;
position:absolute;  
top:0px;  
left:0px;  
z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: i did not get , what i get you from now you can use 

background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.4); for the effect here a is the alpha which only effect the element in which aplha/opacity applied to not the child div's also or child element .... child element wiil not effected by parent opacity just include one line and delete all opacity property from the style ... :)